# Lose relationship from parent border CSS color

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

I need my submenu links to have a different border-color than the parents list one.

**My menu**

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="menuActive"><a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class='children'>
        <li><a href="#">subLink</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">subLink</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">subLink</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**My CSS :**

```
#menu li a{
border-bottom-width:2px;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:red;
text-decoration:none;
}

.children li a{
border-bottom-color:blue;
background:lightgray;
}
```

As you can see, my subLinks get red border, how can set blue ones just for them ?
[See it in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzvXr/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `#menu .children a`.

This is a problem concerning [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/kzvXr/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on CSS Specificity http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/